# Multiple Owl-Carousel in a single page not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I am trying to get multiple owl-carousels to work. While the first instance works beautifully, the next ones don't display at all. Is there any easy fix?

Comment: Works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/rgu8f4j7/ Set different id for another slider/carousel, maybe?

Comment: @nevermind working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Up to version 1.3.3 the instance is on the ID.

In the version 2.0.0 the instance is about CLASS.

Answer (score 0):

Actually @rubenscd it's the other way around...as of version 2.2 the id is what is used.